# Can't set image as the background of UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uicolor

I have seen lots of questions in stackoverflow with the same issue, but none of the solutions helped me. I have used the following code to set a custom image as the background of a label:

```
labelBackgroundImageOriginal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paper.jpg"];
labelBackgroundImageSize = myLabel.frame.size;    
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(labelBackgroundImageSize);
[labelBackgroundImageOriginal drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, labelBackgroundImageSize.width, labelBackgroundImageSize.height)];    
labelBackgroundImageNew = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:labelBackgroundImageNew];
```

But the label background was still white and the image didn't show up. Then I tried with the various solutions that were given under different questions like the following one by one:

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myLabel.opaque = NO;
```

But none of them seem to be working as well. Is there actually a way out of this?

Comment: Have you checked if your `labelBackgroundImageSize` is {0, 0, 0, 0} before drawing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` directly with your image ? It works fine for me.

```
UILabel *test = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 100)];
test.text = @"TEST";
test.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyPicture"]];
[self.view addSubview:test];
```

**EDIT :** I've tried your code and it works fine ! Have you checked if `myLabel.frame.size` value is not null ?